# How to grouping and aggregation using Gremlin

Tags: graphql, gremlin, amazon-neptune

1. we have part vertex and job vertex
2. parts vertex linked to job vertex with relationship 'parts used in job'
3. I have a set of parts as input say 10 parts. For these 10 parts can you identify possible jobs. The output I need is like
   job1: "[Part1,Part2,part3]"
   job2: "[part2,part4]"

{"gremlin":"g.V().hasLabel('Parts').has('~id', within('2197001','6D9157','6V8636','336027','6V3831','2554534','2531351')).as('part').out('part_used_in_job').as('job').select('job', 'part').group().by('job').by(select('part').values('~id').fold())"}
{'detailedMessage': 'java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element', 'requestId': '49551d9e-e22f-4e92-99bc-77fbf1b1784b', 'code': 'UnsupportedOperationException', 'message': 'java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element'}
"""

```
g.V().hasLabel('Parts').has('~id', within('2197001','6D9157','6V8636','336027','6V3831','2554534','2531351'))
  .as('part')
  .out('part_used_in_job')
  .as('job')
  .select('job', 'part')
  .group()
    .by('job')
    .by(select('part').values('~id').fold())
```

"""

Comment: Hello - I see you shared your query but it's not clear from the question what precisely is not working that you need help with. It looks like you are on the right track using `group...by`. Are you able to update the question and show the output you are currently getting? Also, it will be much easier for people to offer a tested answer if you can include the `addV` and `addE` steps that build a sample graph that can be used to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: Let me re-phrase the question. 

1. I have two types of vertex (parts & jobs)
2. parts are linked to jobs (using relationship 'part_used_in_job'). This is many to many relationships.
3. For a given set of parts, I need to identify the parts combination with matching job. 

e.g. JOb1 is associated with Part1, Part2, Part3, Part4
Job2 is associated with Part1,Part6 and so on..

Updated the query and error in the main post.

Comment: I will try to have a look. If you have some test data that builds a sample graph handy that would be super helpful. That error in general happens because a step in the query is expecting to receive an element (like a node or an edge) but instead it received a map. It's probably coming as a result of the `select('job','part')` One tangential side note, rather than using `~id` you can just use `id` or even simpler just call `hasId` instead of `has`. What does the query do if you just remove the `select` step?